# Java Program's Performance question

Tags: java, performance, sockets

I have a java program with following logic:

```
i) Open a socket server and wait for messages from client

ii) Read messages received(fixed length records of about 233 bytes).

iii) on each message receive, call a process function.

iv) process function does follwing
 - add the record to the string builder.

 - if (length of stringbuilder > configured buffer size) {

   process this buffer

   } else {

      add the new record to buffer

   }
```

now when I try this program with 1 million records, each 233 bytes, it takes about 5 min 30 sec to finish. I want to reduce this time. Bulk of the time here is being wasted in this process function.

I was checking if I could get some advice on how to re-organize this process() to get better performance. 
My use case is to get the records and read them until they reach a configured buffer size ( like 50 Mb or 500 MB or 1 GB). Once they reach this size, process it and write to a file system.

Comment: @user656189 If the time is being spent in the process function and not on the data transmission what we need to see is what you are doing in the process function, don't you think?

Comment: have you considered using some form of performance testing plugins for your IDE to see where your bottlenecks are?

Comment: @Endophage - cud you suggest some options for this ?

Comment: JProfiler is good but not cheap.  You might be able to get by with the 10 day evaluation though...  There's another one that I used a year or so ago but unfortunately the name is eluding my memory...

Answer (score 0):

How many cores do you have on your system?  You can create a threadpool with a number of threads equivalent to the [number of cores on your system](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29) and create a runnable that calls process inside a thread within the pool.  That might speed things up a bit for you.

We'll need more info on processing if you only have one core.  Is your CPU pegged in your test?  What OS, etc?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of "micro-optimisations":

1. Create your StringBuilder with the correct initial size(e.g. 1GB).
2. Do not recreate the StringBuilder each time; reuse it by setting setLength(0)

But I'm not sure such micro-optimisations will have much impact. Maybe you could post more of your code?

- Why is the data stored in the intermediate buffer? If all you are doing is writing it to a filesystem would it be better just to write one record at a time using a BufferedWriter?
- Do the messages have to be processed in the order they arrived? If not you could use an ExecutorService to parallelize the processing.

Comment: i) I do micro-optimizations you speicfied. I create stringbuilder only once and re-user it by clearing it after use as: sb.delete(0, sb.length());   ii) Data is stored in intermediate buffer as I am processing this buffer once we reach it's size and converting it to Hadoop key-value format and then writing these records to HadoopFile System. iii) Could you point me to some example of Executor Service ?

Comment: The Executor Service I was thinking of was the standard http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html. If you are using Hadoop then I understand your need to use really large files, but I'm not sure there's any need for an intermediate buffer - could you do: read record; write converted format to Hadoop; close current Hadoop file after 1GB has been written? Also, as others have suggested, it is important to profile your code (if you've not already done so). There's no point optimising the wrong bit of code...

Comment: sb.delete is the wrong tool for the job, it will delete the chars 0..length and bring forward the remaining chars, and you are not really interested in that. What you want is sb.setLength(0) which will just ignore the contents and start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that most of the 5:30 mins can be chalked up to network communication overheads of one form or another.  I'd recommend the following (most important first):

- If you are using UDP, switch to TCP.  For something like this you are likely to get better throughput with a stream-based transport than a message-based transport.
- On the client and server ends, make sure that you have wrapped the socket streams with buffered streams.
- If the client and server are on the same host, use a loopback IP address (e.g. 127.0.0.1).
- If the server-side processing is CPU intensive (and you have multiple cores), do the processing in a separate thread to the thread that reads the messages.
- Consider using NIO for reading / writing the data.
- Consider not converting the data to character form on the server side ... though if it is really text, this would make processing difficult.

---

And before you do **any** of that, profile your client and server-side applications and see if that reveals any unexpected bottlenecks.

Comment: thanks ! this is helpful. What tools can I use to profile my client and server side apps ?

Comment: Try VisualVM - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Some back of envelope sanity checks:

- You are sending 233*1M bytes=1.864Gb over a socket, this is will take
  different amounts of time depending on your bandwidth and NIC but to
  sketch some baseline figures if you got a 100Mb card you are looking
  at 20 seconds right there before any real network latency hit you. In reality this is likely to be much higher unless you are on localhost or on great hardware and connectivity.
- Encoding 233 bytes into a String takes roughly 260 ns(on my machine) using new String(bytes[]) so you are looking at 1M*0.25us = 250 millis.

So off the bat bytes to String is not the issue, and I would also guess StringBuilder.append is not that bad(it copies the char array in). You will be churning allot of memory for all those strings and byte buffers and that may cause some slow down. To avoid the memory churn you can use Charset.newDecoder to get a decoder(keep and reuse) and write the ByteBuffer you get off the wire directly into a reusable CharBuffer. You mention some formatting of the strings, this can be costly when done wrong but unless you are doing something complex I wouldn't think that's the problem.

A more likely cause for your issue is network latency, you can test that theory by writing a dummy program which just reads the data and throws it away.
Another likely suspect is the part of your code which writes to the file or to disk, but with no further info it's hard to help.
Also, if you are new to profiling you can use hand rolled timing to verify your theories:

```
long start = System.nanotime();
process(data);
long took = System.nanotime() - start;
```

Sum up how long you spent in process and you got an idea of where the time went.